# How to insert a space between all digits in Kotlin?

Tags: string, kotlin

I want to transform a string like this

```
Turn right on A2309
```

to

```
Turn right on A2 3 0 9
```

Whats the simplest way to do this using kotlin predicates?

Comment: What do you mean by "kotlin predicates"? There is `java.util.function.Predicate`, but that isn't a Kotlin-specific thing...

Comment: @Sweeper What I meant was some function similar to .filter{} which lets me transform each character individually based on if its a digit or not. However your solution looks very elegant. Trying it out now.

Comment: You should not assume functional-style programming is inherently better. It is always a matter of code readability and efficiency. There are many cases where functional code is much more readable than imperative one. But there are also opposite cases. Your problem could be solved with `zipWithNext()` + `flatMap()`, but I would say it will be both less efficient and less readable than `buildString()` with good old loop.

Comment: Agreed. This issue isn't about solvability. Its about readability. Check out the answer I posted. It doesn't solve the problem as well as the regex does, but this is what I was looking for. I thought that changing a string char-by-char must be a common requirement so this function must have existed in kotlin, hence the question.

Comment: You said in comments that one of your main goals was to learn this kind of transformations, so I have one additional thing to discuss: proper naming. You probably misunderstood the meaning of "predicate". Using transformations like `filter()`, `map()`, `reduce()`, etc. is usually called [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming](functional programming). In Kotlin it is often called an _idiomatic_ way of solving things.

Comment: "Predicate" is usual name for some kind of algorithm that is used to match elements - it designates if an element matches provided... predicates or not. Thus, you will find a lambda named "predicate" in functions like `filter()`, but also in simple `find()`. You will find predicates in database libraries when you need to specify, which rows to match (`WHERE` clause in SQL). But it doesn't make sense to use "predicate" name for a lambda that transforms one value to another - as in your answer below. Such lambda is usually named "transform", "mapper", "selector", etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to use a regex:

```
val string = "Turn right on A2309"
val result = string.replace(Regex("(\\d)(?=\\d)"), "$1 ")
```

This regex finds digits that are followed by another digit, and captures the first one in group 1. We then replace by group 1 followed by a space.

> What I meant was some function similar to `.filter{}` which lets me transform each character individually based on if its a digit or not.

In that case, I can think of `buildString` with `forEach`:

```
val string = "Turn right on A2309"
val result = buildString {
    string.forEach {
        append(it)
        if (it.isDigit()) {
            append(' ')
        }
    }
}
```

Or `flatMap` then `joinToString` (this will create a bunch of unnecessary lists):

```
val result = string.flatMap {
    if (!it.isDigit()) {
        listOf(it)
    } else {
        listOf(it, ' ')
    }
}.joinToString(separator = "")
```

Note that unlike the regex solution, this will add a space after each digit. If you want to only add spaces after digits which are followed by other digits, you will need to check 2 digits at a time (e.g. use something like `zipWithNext`). You’d also need to add the last character separately, since that isn’t the start of a pair. IMO, at that point it’s too much hassle and you’ll be better off using a regex.

Comment: Thanks Sweeper! This solution is elegant and works perfectly. I didn't even know this was possible using Regex. Keeping the question open for now in case someone answers with a kotlin specific solution.

Comment: @abhiank I added solutions that "lets me transform each character individually based on if its a digit or not".

Comment: Perfect! These are the possibilities I was looking for. However, your regex solution still remains the most elegant one. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Both your `buildString()` and `flatMap()` solutions aren't correct ones, because they add a space char after each digit, not only between digits. `zipWithNext()` would solve this.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood "trailing space" in your answer. I thought you mean only the space at the end of the string. But these solutions will convert e.g. "4ever" to "4 ever".

Comment: @broot ah I see. Now thinking back, I totally cannot figure out what my thought process was when writing that... Edited.

Answer (score 0):

This is an extension function which takes a predicate and transforms each char in a string.

```
fun String.transform(predicate: (Char) -> String): String {
    val stringBuilder = StringBuilder("")

    for (index in 0 until length) {
        val element = get(index)
        stringBuilder.append(predicate(element))
    }
    return stringBuilder.toString()
}
```

For this particular case, it can used like this

```
val result = "Turn left on A2342".transform { if(it.isDigit()) "$it " else "$it" }
```

This solves the need of a function which can used be transform each character, but it has a flaw for this particular usecase which is that it will leave a trailing empty space after the last digit.

Comment: You really overcomplicated this ;-) Your whole `transform()` function could be replaced with: `map(predicate).joinToString("")`. Also, it does not only add space after the last digit. It will convert e.g. "4ever" to "4 ever". Give me a sec, I'll write you a functional-style and fully working solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need a functional style solution, here you go:

```
fun String.splitDigits() : String {
    if (isEmpty()) return ""
    return  zipWithNext { a, b ->
        if (a.isDigit() && b.isDigit()) "$a " else a
    }.joinToString("") + last()
}

"Turn right on A2309".splitDigits()
```

Comment: I had a simple similar solution before I even posted the question. The aim was to learn about functional transforming methods and I now know flatMap{} and zipWithNext{} and the quite elegant regex solution. Thanks to you sweeper for that..